# How to insert multiple choices in to the database and display

Tags: django

**My models is:**

```
class LabRequest(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lab_test = models.ManyToManyField(Lab)
```

**My Form**

```
class LabRequestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LabRequest
        fields = ['ticket', 'lab_test']
        widgets = {
            'lab_test': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }
```

**My view**

```
def LabRequestToGenerateView(request):
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.created_by = request.user.id
        obj.save()

    return render(request, 'dashboard/laboratory_request.html', {'form': form})
```

**My Template**

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="form-group float-right">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" > <i
                class="fa fa-save"></i>
            Save</button>
    </div>
</form>



{% for rl in rl %}

<label for=""> Ticket: {{ rl.ticket }} </label>
<p> Lab Tests: {{ rl.lab_test }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

So, It's displaying as a checkbox that's good. but when i want to save some data it saves only ticket, not lab_test? So, how do I save both?

[image: As you see it displays only ticket which is **Ubed Gedi ALi** and where I wanted to see **lab_test** it shows me **appname.modelname.None**]

As you see it displays only ticket which is **Ubed Gedi ALi** and where I wanted to see **lab_test** it shows me **appname.modelname.None**

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the place where you display the data, not where you save it. Please show the view and template where you do that.

Comment: see, I updated my post, kindly help

Comment: `lab_test` is a many-to-many field, you need to iterate over `rl.lab_test.all`. (And in your existing loop, you shouldn't use the same name for the item as you do for the queryset.)

Comment: After doing this <p> Lab Tests: {{ rl.lab_test.all }}</p> the output is Lab Tests: <QuerySet []>

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) - you didn't call `form.save_m2m()`.

Comment: You saved me, Thank you very much.